# Group by a column but concat another column with comma delimited

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table with `company_name` and `RegistrationId` column.

How to write a query so that I can do `group by company_name` but concatenate all values of `RegistrationId` into a string column (say `AllIDs`) with comma like `123,456,789`?

Answer (score 3):

This can be expressed as:

T
| summarize AllIds=make_list(RegistrationId) by company_name

You can use make_set() function to create unique set (without repetitions of ids).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction

If you need later to format a string from array - use strcat_array() function:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/strcat-arrayfunction